# Java Scala-STM typecasting error when reading from TArray

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, stm

I have a (ungraded) programming assignment in which I have to implement a circular queue using scala-stm from https://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/.

I have a get function:

```
public E get() {
    E item = STM.atomic(new Callable<E>(){ public E call()
    {
        if (isEmpty()) STM.retry(); 
        E item = (E) items.refViews().apply(tail.get());
        //STM.increment(count, -1);
        return item;
    }});
    return item;
```

Now here I have to cast to E, (E) items.refViews().apply(tail.get()); or I get a compiler error. Which sort of makes sense.
But in the unit test this item is tried to be casted to int, to verify that it's the same value as it was when put into the Circular Queue.

But I get the following classCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class scala.concurrent.stm.ccstm.TArrayImpl$$anon$3 cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (scala.concurrent.stm.ccstm.TArrayImpl$$anon$3 is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Though the object was originally an integer, it can't be cast back. 
How should I go about it? 
I have studied the documentation in detail and it seems to actually do it in the same way, but for Strings.
When I try strings, I don't get this exception anymore, but the cast back turns into the name of the TArray Object.
I am doing something wrong, but I am not sure what.
Thank you for any hints!

Comment: 1. Is scala-stm choice part of the assignment? The library looks like it's been abandoned, so if I could pick, I would pick something else. 2. Why are you using Scala libraries from Java? It's a pain to work with the code this way.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Oh, I didn't know this, one slide says it's relatively new and might be an easier way then to use locks. I am thinking it's maybe just a way to teach us about stm and tm and not have us learn a whole new language. 
Our professor seems fond of it though. Edit; and yes, scala-stm is part of the assignment.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I also found my mistake though, I'm returning a refview object and not the actual object. See my own answer below if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake.
This:

```
E item = (E) items.refViews().apply(tail.get());
```

Should be:
    E item = items.apply(tail.get());

the .refViews().apply() returns a view object that is read only of the variable referenced in memory if I understood correctly.
.apply() directly returns the actual object that the view is referencing in mem.